# Inconsistent time discrepancy synchronize

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, asus-xtion-pro-live, synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to make a node which subscribes both rgb image and point cloud from asus xtion pro live. It seems like there is inconsistent time discrepancy between these two and synchronizing does not work well in this situation. Does anybody know how to deal with this kind of issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375305/inconsistent-time-discrepancy-synchronize/) by [kidpaul](https://answers.ros.org/users/72845/kidpaul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2021-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, you need to use buffers in order to synchronize asynchronous nodes, this is provided by ros (python, C++) so you do not need to code it, have a look at [message_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters).

---

Originally posted by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) with karma: 42 on 2021-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0